# Sales Cloud EE license

Tags: licenses, enterprise, sales-cloud, userlicense

We have a few users with Sales Cloud EE users. We are looking to potentially switch a few of the users to chatter users. Can we swap that user type and go from Sales Cloud EE --> Chatter plus or chatter free or would we need to deactivate the sales cloud user and then create a new profile?

Answer (score 0):

You can't "downgrade" users, so you will need to create new users for these users.